# javascript - get base64 from canvas also with style

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, base64

I create dynamically a canvas element and also I add to this canvas a class style, it display very well
But when I generate the base64 using toDataUrl(), it generated without style class that I added

```
document.body.insertBefore(structtaUrl, document.body.firstChild);
let c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
c.setAttribute('class', 'canv');
console.log(c.toDataURL('image/png'));
```

any idea why !

Comment: I don't understand you.  The method canvas.toDataURL() returns an url that can be used as a value for the src attribute of an image. An url has no class. Please give a code example.

Comment: @enxaneta I added the code ! yes toDataUrl returns a url as base64 but when I see it I found it without style that exist in class "canv"

Comment: @enxaneta my style rotate de canvas but when I get dataUrl is not rotated

Comment: If your question is **how to** the answer is: you can rotate the context of the canvas with the method `context.rotate()`. You need to use radians not degrees. If your question is **why**, probably because the data URI is containing a representation of the image painted on the context of the canvas regardless of the transformation the canvas element

Comment: If you want to preserve the style consider using html2canvas